# Opencart 2.1 how to set default category in product form?

Tags: php, mysql, opencart2.x

I am using opencart 2.1.

**Question:**

In Admin Product Form (adding new or edit products), is there a way to:

1. Set default category when no category is choose?
2. Remove the default category when a category is choose?

**Purpose:**

Currently I have several staffs adding new products without specify the category because they are not sure which category suit the product best.

My current store have more than 5000 products and it is hard to identify which products have no category.

**My Solution:**

Therefore I want to create "No Category" category and auto set to "No Category" category if my staffs leave the choose category blank when adding new products.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a little bit hard coated but it is possible. Opencart does not provides you such facility. You can put some `checks` in your model and do the trick. Do you want me to elaborate?

Comment: That would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: can you add me on skype? My id is `syed_ali_zia`

Comment: I am sorry, I don't have skype. Can't you just show the answer here?

Comment: Create a new category. In database, check its id. Then in your model, you have to check if $data['categories'] (the variable of categories associated to it) is empty, you manually assign in to your "No category". Do you get what I mean?

Comment: It is easy. You have to know the structure. Path, structure and flow.